# How to write function overloading and object calling in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

can any one tell me the small example in function overloading and method calling
   in asp.net
   can we create a object in asp

How to create a method overloading in asp.net

Comment: you can create `class` then create its `.dll` and add that reference to your asp.net application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I simply Overload Two methods of Signature `(int,int)` and `(int,float)`.

Create `Class` and Add this in Your `App_code` folder in `asp.net`

Then You can Access This Class in code behind by

> ```
> Class1 cs1=new Class1;
> ```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
///



    public class Class1
    {

        public int Sum(int A, int B)
        {
            return A + B;
        }

        public float Sum(int A, float B)
        {
            return A + B;
        }
    }
```

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         Class1 c1=new Class1();
         c1.Sum(10, 20);
         c1.Sum(10, 5.5f); } in aspx.cs file i wrote this

Comment: so what else remaining ?? methods will return results

Comment: replace `c1.Sum(10, 20)` with `Response.Write(c1.Sum(10, 20)+ "</br>");` and `c1.Sum(10, 5.5f)` and 
`Response.Write(c1.Sum(10, 5.5f));`  you will get result